# Promiscuous mode in AODV NS2

Tags: protocols, tcl, ns2

As I do my project of "detection and prevention of black hole attack, I need to monitor the packet flow to the nighbouring node. That for, I need to use the promiscuous mode in AODV. I have found some tutorial in the following link but there too its not complete and i have never found any other material.

http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~adhoc1/nshowto1.html

http://greenw.blogspot.in/2006/08/support-promiscuous-mode-in-aodv.html

There is something like "// put your code here " in AODV::tap(const Packet *p) But I dont get what exactly I need to put there so that I will be able to monitor the packet flow.

It will be very helpful, if anybody can give some light to these, as I am very much towards the end of the course. Its bit urgent.

Thanking you.......

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to achieve this

1. Put that node which you want to monitor on hub port and you should plug in that hub on another port and use wireshark to watch traffic from or to that node.
2. If you both are on same switch use port mirroring to watch his traffic.
3. Linux has feature of prom mode.